# Merge Pandas Dataframes based on same hour

Tags: python, pandas

I have a history of values at hour intervals, and I want to add a column to the dataframe that puts the average at that hour across every day. So if the average value for 4:00 is 34, I want every date with the hour 4:00 to have 34 in a column called 'Average'. Right now I can get the averages in a table with the hours, but can't seem to get it to join in more than one spot.

```
Timestamp              Value
2018-04-12 13:00:00     12.0
2018-04-12 12:00:00     38.0
2018-04-12 11:00:00     12.0
2018-04-12 10:00:00     28.0
2018-04-12 09:00:00     26.0
2018-04-12 08:00:00     22.0
...

       Average
00:00   7.0
01:00   0.0
02:00   0.0
03:00   0.0
04:00   0.0
05:00   1.5
06:00   11.5
07:00   11.0
08:00   10.5
...
```

Goal:

```
Timestamp              Value    Average
2018-04-12 13:00:00     12.0      8.5
2018-04-12 12:00:00     38.0      8.4
2018-04-12 11:00:00     12.0     15.5
2018-04-12 10:00:00     28.0     19.0
2018-04-12 09:00:00     26.0     12.4
2018-04-12 08:00:00     22.0     10.5
```

I've tried merging, and joining, but haven't figured out how to loop through manually to do it.

Comment: Can you show how you got the average, also, maybe a bit more of your dataframe? Right now it has no duplicate hours to calculate an average for.

Comment: If the average is precomputed and you simply want to merge two dataframes, you can use `left` [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html). Make sure  the dataframe with `Timestamps` is the `left` dataframe.

Comment: From this cut and paste it's not clear whether your 'Timestamp' column is an actual timestamp including both date and time, a string including both date and time, or an index consisting of date and a column of the time.  You'll need to process it differently prior to doing the merge to get the hour by itself if it's one of the first two options.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, the answer below nailed it on the head. The Hour field was stringformatted but it's easy enough to turn them back into datetimes. I got the average by:
`group_date = [datetime.datetime.strftime(e, '%H:%M') for e in df.index]`
`avgs = df.groupby(group_date)['Value'].mean()'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one is pretty simple if you convert them to datetime using `pd.to_datetime()` Then you can merge on `.dt.hour`.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp': ['2018-04-12 13:00:00','2018-04-12 12:00:00',
    '2018-04-12 11:00:00','2018-04-12 10:00:00','2018-04-12 09:00:00','2018-04-12 08:00:00'],
    'Value': [12, 38, 12, 28, 26, 22]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Hour': ['00:00','01:00','02:00','03:00','04:00',
                            '05:00','06:00','07:00', '08:00'],
                   'Average': [7, 0,0,0,0,1.5, 11.5, 11, 10.5]})

df1['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.Timestamp)
df2['Hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df2.Hour)
```

Now okay, it converts the hours to a datetime object with today as the current date, but since we are just merging on hour it doesn't matter.

```
df1.merge(df2, left_on=df1.Timestamp.dt.hour, right_on=df2.Hour.dt.hour, how='left').drop(columns='Hour')
#            Timestamp  Value  Average
#0 2018-04-12 13:00:00     12      NaN
#1 2018-04-12 12:00:00     38      NaN
#2 2018-04-12 11:00:00     12      NaN
#3 2018-04-12 10:00:00     28      NaN
#4 2018-04-12 09:00:00     26      NaN
#5 2018-04-12 08:00:00     22     10.5
```

There are only so many non-merges because the sample data you gave only has 08:00 overlapping in each set.

**Or without converting:**

```
mt = pd.to_datetime(df1.Timestamp).dt.hour
mh = pd.to_datetime(df2.Hour).dt.hour

df1.merge(df2, left_on=mt, right_on=mh, how='left').drop(columns=['Hour'])
```

Comment: Nice, however you can remove the `.values` after `.hour`.

Comment: Oh yeah good catch. I forgot why I though I needed that. I'll update it

Comment: Worked perfectly. I didn't know about the `dt.hour' for the "on" values. Neat trick. Thanks!